# Replace all instances of http://www.*** with another address

Tags: php, regex, replace

I have a string that contains several links on a website, but I need to change them to link to another website.

For example, `http://www.site2.com/contact` and `http://www.site3.com/contact` would need to become `http://www.mainsite.com/contact`. The URL's here and `/contact` are just examples, the reality is I need to find all instances of `http://` and replace the conent between that and the next `/` with a new URL.

I there a way of doing this through `preg_replace()` (or similar if this in to the best option)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
$pattern = '#(http://)([a-z0-9.-])+/+([a-z0-9.-])#i';
$oldurl = 'http://www.site2.com/contact';
$replacement = '$1www.mainsite.com/$3';

$newurl = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $oldurl);
```

**EDIT:**

```
$string = 'String with many URLs';

echo replaceUrls($string);

function replaceUrls($string) {
    $pattern = '#(http://)([a-z0-9.-])+/+([a-z0-9.-]|)#i';
    $replacement = '$1www.mainsite.com/$3'; 

    return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ShogunArts, but this is not quite there. The `contact` page was just an example, but I can just remove that I guess? Also, the `$subject` is a string, not an array, although looking at the docs I don't think that matters? However, this is not actually replacing the URL's. I've copied the string that I need to run the replacements [in to this Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/EdZ2tFTA), just so you can see what I am working with. Thanks.

Comment: Just change the pattern to this: `$pattern = '#(http://)([a-z0-9.-])(/)#i';` and I made an error with $replacement, this should be `$replacement = '$1www.mainsite.com/'` and sure you can use `$subject` to be a String.

Comment: Edit my answer with a function (tested with your string and it works)

Comment: Thanks muchly, very much appriciated.

Answer (score 3):

Update: This answer does *not* reflect the question, because the question was slightly misleading first. Have a look at Jeroens or ShogunArts.des answer

No need for regular expressions

```
$string = str_replace(
  array('http://www.site2.com/','http://www.site3.com/'),
  'http://www.mainsite.com/',
  $string
);
```

[`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str-replace)

Comment: It seems to me the OP wants to change **all** URLs, without knowing which, so you'll have to use regular expressions.

Comment: @Jeroen No, it doesn't: "contains several links on _a_ website".

Comment: @KingCrunch - Jeroen is correct, there will be several different URL's, and the ones listed were just as an example. I've edited my question to make it clearer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. Match the urls: http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls
2. Use [preg_replace_callback()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php), and within the callback function:

   1. Use [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to get all parts
   2. Replace the `host` part to `mainsite.com`

Answer (score 0):

replace regex `(?<=http://)(www\.site2\.com)(?=/contact)` with new site name